# MVC Модульные контроллеры

Tags: php, mvc, движок

Как и все программисты на PHP, года три назад я взялся за создание личного движка для фриланса, все было хорошо, пока я не решил измерять время загрузки страницы, и оно было не мало. Сложность возникла в том, что модули, которые добавлены в движок, могут также создавать личные контроллеры. Вся система разбилась на 3 типа контроллеров: `Системные`, `Пользовательские` и `Контроллеры модулей`. Подгружаю я контроллеры через Autoloader: `\Controller\Main` - контроллер главной страницы (пользовательский), например, `\System\Controller\Installer` - контроллер системный, для установки модулей, он лежит глубоко в директориях движка. А третий тип контроллеров может быть `\Module\$MODULE_NAME\Controller\Users` и он хранится в `Modules/$MODULE_NAME/Content`. Если в роутере через foreach перебирать все модули и искать в них контроллеры - слишком долго. Должен быть способ проще и быстрее, почти пол года уже ломаю голову, может вы что-нибудь подскажете

Comment: Самописки для себя - ок. Но для роботы это зло... страдает все. И расширяемось и отсутствие поддержки сторонними разработчиками... а по поводу вашей проблемы - юзайте htaccess - правила... сразу будет лететь на нужный контроллер нужного модуля...

Comment: кэшируйте конфиги модулей.

Comment: 1. Включите APC поможет хорошо, он и инклюды в кэш ложит. 2. Часто самый медленный компонент это рауты посмотрите может там можно подтянуть. Ну и что остальные советовали.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не одиноки в писках. Множество современных фреймворков сталкивается с проблемой которую вы описали.
Чаще всего эта проблема решается кешем.
Контроллеры появляются сравнительно редко, а страницы запрашиваются очень часто.
Предлагаю создать аналог *composer dump-autoload*
Каждый раз после изменения исходного кода проекта запускать скрипт который будет генерировать файл со списком всех контроллеров. 
А при запросе страницы загружать готовый список.